# How to refresh a UIVIewController with a proper Pagination techniques with Firebase as backend?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Please help me out. I created an app similar to Instagram with Firebase as backend. The Homefeed where the posts from the user and all the users he follows are is a  **UIViewController**. When starting the app the ***fetchPosts()*** method is executed. The **fetchPosts()**-method fills the posts-array with all post-objects. When this process is finished I call collectionView.reloadData that executes the collectionView methods like **cellForItemAt** etc..  and  the posts are shown. If there are some new posts the user can refresh the ViewController by dragging it down and the refreshControl appears. When the refreshControl appears Im deleting the posts array and call the fetchPosts()-method. The problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes I received following **error: Thread1: EXC_BAD_Instruction... fatal error: Index out of range**

I tried to check weather the refreshing is finished with  **if !self.refreshControl.isRefreshing** .  **cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]**

But still received that error messages. I don't have any idea how to solve that issue and why the index is out of range. How can I include a pagination technique for my problem. Please help me I stuck into that problem since weeks and there is no solution that I found. What happens if my posts array contains 1000 post Objects ?

```
  // Posts-Arry
     var posts = [Post]()

  // RefreshControl 
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
         refreshControl.
       addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged) 


    func handleRefresh(){
    posts.removeAll()
    fetchPosts()
   }

     // Load post-data from Firebase database and 
      create the posts Object and fill the posts-Array

    func fetchPosts(){

     .....

       self.posts.append(post)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }
```

The app just continues refreshing and I get the error message in Xcode

[image]

Comment: post your whole function fetchPosts

Comment: @J.Doe can I contact you via Facebook, Skype or gmail please ?

Comment: Please upload your project to GitHub or post your whole code here